# Can I merge torrents which have the same files from two different sources?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

Thanks for having interest in my question.

I found a torrent which I had the exact same content but no seeder (I will call this A). I want to be the seeder of the A torrent, but unfortunately, the content I had is torrented from a different source (I will call this B), and every time I try to add the A torrent to uTorrent, it only adds the trackers from A to B.

So, my question is, can I seed the same files for different torrents?

I tried searching, but I keep getting irrelevant results, as I can't find any other word than "merging" to describe this (I'm new to torrent btw). Thank you a lot, for being able to read through all of this nonsense.

Comment: To re-establish this dead torrent, download the torrent with no seeders and start the torrent, this will create the directory and file structures, they will be empty files of course, once this is done stop that torrent and close your bittorrent client, now copy the full files you have to where the new torrent download is with the empty files, essentially replacing them with completed files. Start the bittorrent client and you should be seeding the once dead torrent, you may have to force a file check on that torrent before it starts seeding.

Comment: What @Moab suggests is the way. Keep in mind, if the files are not exactly the same, your torrent will not work, but also, you will be flagged as bad seeder and get banned in the swarm, so neither torrent will work for you anymore.